# Unwanted change of resolution from 1366x768 to 1280x720

Tags: display-resolution

I set my screen, using setting->display->screen->resolution to 1366x768(16:9) when I installed Ubuntu two months ago, which worked well until yesterday.

Now I see 1280x720 (16:9) with a black frame at the screen borders.

I use Ubuntu as my primary OS, and have for the last 2 months, with no virtualization.

my laptop's details:
model name  : AMD E2-9000 RADEON R2, 4 COMPUTE CORES 2C+2G
description: Motherboard
       product: Squirtle_SR
       vendor: SR
       physical id: 0
       version: V1.12
       serial: NBGNV1100D83303DB97600
          product: AMD E2-9000 RADEON R2, 4 COMPUTE CORES 2C+2G
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Stoney [Radeon R2/R3/R4/R5 Graphics] (rev d2) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 1192
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 43
    Memory at e8000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=128M]
    Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=8M]
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
    Memory at f0d00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: 
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
    Kernel modules: amdgpu
     *-memory
          description: System memory
          physical id: 0
          size: 3883MiB
     *-cpu
          product: AMD E2-9000 RADEON R2, 4 COMPUTE CORES 2C+2G
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
          physical id: 1
          bus info: cpu@0
          size: 2123MHz
          width: 64 bits
          capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc rep_good acc_power nopl nonstop_tsc cpuid extd_apicid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs xop skinit wdt lwp fma4 tce nodeid_msr tbm perfctr_core perfctr_nb bpext ptsc mwaitx cpb hw_pstate ssbd ibpb vmmcall fsgsbase bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 xsaveopt arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold avic v_vmsave_vmload vgif overflow_recov cpufreq
     *-pci:0
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Root Complex
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz

```
    *-display
         description: VGA compatible controller
         product: Stoney [Radeon R2/R3/R4/R5 Graphics]
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
         physical id: 1
         bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
         version: d2
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
         configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
         resources: irq:43 memory:e8000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f07fffff ioport:3000(size=256) memory:f0d00000-f0d3ffff memory:c0000-dffff
    *-multimedia:0
         description: Audio device
         product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
         physical id: 1.1
         bus info: pci@0000:00:01.1
         version: 00
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
         resources: irq:40 memory:f0d60000-f0d63fff
    *-pci:0
         description: PCI bridge
         product: Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Root Port
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
         physical id: 2.1
         bus info: pci@0000:00:02.1
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:26 ioport:1000(size=4096) memory:f0e00000-f0ffffff ioport:f1000000(size=2097152)
```

How may I troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: What's your laptop? Please open a terminal, and run `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "model name" && sudo lshw | grep -A5 "Moth" && lshw | grep product | head -n1 && lspci  -v -s  $(lspci | grep ' VGA ' | cut -d" " -f 1) && lshw | grep -v "loop"` then click [edit] to add the facts to your question. Please do not click Add Comment, please use [edit] instead. Editing tips are at https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code .